# Classes with defined functions that won't call correctly

Tags: python

The question is noted in the title. It might be a question of details, as always, but still, any help would be appreciated.

```
#  create a supervilan class

class supervilan:
     size = ""
     color = ""
     powers = ""
     weapons = ""
     special_ability = ""

     def customs(self):
         print(self.name + " has a supercool and technologic advanced suit.")

     def organic_gear(self, gear):
        print(self.name + " use they´re" + gear + " with mastery and precision!")
```

I reduced the amount of methods to facilitate:

```
# objects

Dracula = supervilan()
Dracula.size = "2.12cm"
Dracula.color = "white"
Dracula.organic_gear("Astucy")

Chimical = supervilan()
Chimical.size = "2.30cm"
Chimical.color = "Caucasian"


Dracula.organic_gear()
Chimical.customs()
```

Comment: How can you print self.name, if name is not a variable of your class?

Comment: Also "they're" means "they are".

Comment: ok, thanks, i forgot to that variable, my bad.

Comment: yes i know, my initial intention was to do another thing, so, i forgot to change the term as well.

Comment: thanks for both observations, but in end the problem continues

Comment: Why do you define attributes like `size` and `color` on class level? You don't use them and create instance level attributes instead (`Dracula.size = "2.12cm"`).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Well, because I was learning the concept, actually, and the first exercise was like that, the following subject was instance level attributes instead. All good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positional arguments are values you put in the brackets of a function (eg: function(arg1,arg2)). The organic_gear function requires two positional arguments as specified when you defined the function (organic_gear(self, gear)). However in your code you call organic_gear without specifying what "self" or "gear" are, and that's why that error message appears. There may be other errors or style improvements to be corrected but I'll leave that to people better versed in classes in python.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should go through the basics of OOPs concept to work with class and instances.

Since you wants to create different instances of your supervilan class with different attribute of (size, color, etc..), you must make them instance variable not class and set default values when you are initializing the instance of your class.

```
class supervilan:
     def __init__(self, name='', size='', color='', powers='', weapons='', special_ability=''):
         self.name = name
         self.size = size
         self.color = color
         self.powers = powers
         self.weapons = weapons

     def customs(self):
         print(self.name + " has a supercool and technologic advanced suit.")

     def organic_gear(self, gear):
         print(self.name + " use they´re" + gear + " with mastery and precision!")
```

Now you can create different instances of your class with different attribute values

```
Dracula = supervilan("Dracula", "2.12cm", "white")


Chimical = supervilan("Chimical", "2.30cm", "Caucasian)
```

Comment: That´s exactly what i am doing, this is part of a course exercise, so, im still learning the concepts, but thanks for taking the time to answer my question.